# Binding checkboxes to array with Knockout.js (MVC Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have a Knockout.js view model that looks like this:

```
"UserName":null,
"FirstName":null,
"LastName":null,
"Countries":{
    "arrCountries":[]
}
```

And a set of country checkboxes that all must be rendered with the same `data-bind` value (I'm using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/MVC3-Html-CheckBoxList-custom-extension) custom CheckBoxListFor helper, which can apply custom HTML to each checkbox, but it's the same custom HTML for each checkbox. It takes a property that lists every available country from my razor view model to create the checkboxes, and then renders some as marked based on another razor view model property).

The checkbox values are integers (1, 2, 3, etc) and it's those integers that I'd like to throw into the `arrCountries` property of the view model.

Here's how a checkbox is rendered as it stands at the moment:

```
<input checked="checked" data_bind="checked: ???" id="Countries.arrCountries107" name="Countries.arrCountries" type="checkbox" value="1"></input>
```

I've proven the concept of using `viewModel.Countries.arrCountries.push(1);` to update the view model (followed by an alert that gives me a count of the elements in arrCountries to prove that the `push` worked), but I can't seem to get the `data-bind` HTML property on the checkboxes to wire up so that they check and uncheck as I send `push` and `remove` commands.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the checked data attribute point to the selected countries. If the checkbox's value is in the array of checkboxes, then it will be checked. It won't otherwise.

```
<input checked="checked" data-bind="checked: Countries" type="checkbox" value="3"></input>
```

Take a look at this fiddle I put up.

http://jsfiddle.net/u8xP9/3/

Comment: Thanks Paolo! Your code made me realise that my `data-bind`s on the checkboxes weren't being rendered properly (`data_bind` in razor code is normally translated to `data-bind` when rendered, but on the custom CheckBoxListFor control, that wasn't happening). An upgrade to v.1.4.2.3 of the control (from v.1.3b) sorted that out. With that fixed, your code got it all working brilliantly! Thanks!